# {FlashDevelop} Building iOS with AIR and FlashDevelop

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, flashdevelop

I'm having trouble using the following tutorial and flashdevelop template to build a flash project for iOS. http://www.codeandvisual.com/2011/exporting-for-iphone-using-air-27-and-flashdevelop-part-four-creating-an-air-certificate-and-compiling-to-ipa/

Whenever I compile my project (using FlashDevelop 3.3.4) I get an error from adl.exe saying "Error loading initial content".

Using the iOS applicationpackager.bat, I get an error saying:  application.xml: error 305: Intial window content SWF version 11 exceeds namespace version http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.0

I'm using air 2.7 and Flex 4.5.1 on Windows XP.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've read your issue is most likely coming from an incorrectly configured application descriptor file:

http://www.leebrimelow.com/?p=2764

That tutorial explains how to configure your descriptor to target IOS using AIR 2.7. Give that a try see if that doesn't fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks! I'm currently finding a workaround LoadBytes, but I'll try that out as soon as I get a second. In the meantime I got this working for me: http://www.pixelthismobile.com/blog/3/04/2011/adt-helper-tool

Comment: I ended up just going with the command line method of packaging mentioned in the article you linked. Ended up being way easier than any of the GUI solutions out there! Thanks for the help.