# Can FlashDevelop deploy to iOS?

Tags: ios, flashdevelop

I have searched the internet looking for a definitive answer to the question of can FlashDevelop deploy to iOS. All the thing's I have read are not very clear and not very certain. I don't have enough money to afford Adobe Flash or Flash Builder so provided I have a Mac is FlashDevelop a suitable replacement that I can make flash games for iOS?

thanks, 
David

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. It looks like FlashDevelop is just a Flash editor, but Flash doesn't run on iOS.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928456/flashdevelop-building-ios-with-air-and-flashdevelop , I assume you intend to crosscompile to Objective-C? Check HaXe too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Good tutorials**

Here are some detailed tutorial here to publish to iOS from FlashDevelop - this kind of template will be integrated in FD in the future:

- http://www.codeandvisual.com/2011/exporting-for-iphone-using-air-27-and-flashdevelop-part-two-creating-an-iphone-project/
- http://connorullmann.com/2011/04/air-2-6-and-ios/

**Workflow optimization**

Please note that since these tutorials the AIR SDK was improved and you can package your IPA in "interpreter" mode, it greatly cuts packaging time and it runs about as fast unless doing really CPU intensive computations.

In your packaging command, use **ipa-test-interpreter** or **ipa-debug-interpreter** instead of the respective **ipa-test** and **ipa-debug** options. This is something to locate and change in the .BAT scripts which do the packaging job.

Answer (score 0):

Via Adobe AIR you can compile for iOS, and with the AIR SDK FlashDevelop can compile AIR / iOS.

I don't think they have FlashDevelop for Mac, though.  I have a macbook pro and use bootcamp to boot in / run windows primarily to use flashdevelop and it works great.

FlashDevelop's project organization and code completion etc is so good, much better than adobe's, definitely worth it.

Answer (score -1):

Although this doesn't answer your question directly, I think this may still help you. Adobe provides free copies of Flash Builder (Standard Ed. only not Premium) if you meet certain conditions.

> We provide free copies of Adobe Flash Builder 4.5 Standard to:
>
> - Students, faculty and staff of eligible educational institutions
> - Software developers who are affected by the current economic condition
>     and are currently unemployed
> - Event attendees who receive a special promotional code at their event

http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/flex/free/index.html

Comment: too bad it doesn't cover open source projects :(

Comment: -1 question was using flashdevelop with clearly mentioning op don't want to use the flash builder.