# Convert as3 Program containing AIR classes to IPA

Tags: air, ipa

How do I compile a program created with as3 in FlashDevelop which uses AIR classes right so I can convert it to an IPA for iPad/iPhone?
The AIR classes I use (File) are not added to the swf.

Comment: What do you mean by saying AIR classes are not added to SWF?

Comment: If you compile the programm you get a swf, which you can't run without the AIR debug launcher, as the AIR classes are missing (error 1014, class not found).
And without those classes it obviously won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you google more about your issue. There are a lot of tutorials and how to's:

http://www.codeandvisual.com/2011/exporting-for-iphone-using-air-27-and-flashdevelop-part-two-creating-an-iphone-project/

Also stackoverflow is a nice search engine for such issues.

[Can FlashDevelop deploy to iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151334/can-flashdevelop-deploy-to-ios)

Comment: Thanks, those where the EXACT tutorials that got me even to the point of seeing something on the iPad.
As it turns out my FlashDevelop project was an as3 one, with the additional files from the AIR-iOS template copied in.
Though the programm wont show anything in debug, the swf is build and can be converted to a working IPA.
Thx

Comment: Strange, how about starting a new empty as3 project with the air template and just add a circle or rectangle in there. This could help you to check if something is wrong with air/template you use or if this works then something is wrong in your code.